# A question about Inverse Function theorem

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

The Inverse Function theorem: Let A be open in $R^n$; let $f: \to R^n$ be of class $C^r$. If $Df(x)$ is non-singular at the point $a$ of $A$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of the point $a$ such that $f$ carries $U$ in a one-to-one fashion onto an open set $V$ of $R^n$ and the inverse function is of class $C^r$

My question is about how to prove that the inverse function is of class $C^r$.

Suppose that the inverse function of $f$ on the given open neighborhood is $g$. The way munkres proves it is by viewing $Dg$ as the composite of three functions:

$g:V \to U$

$D_f:U \to GL(n)$

$Inverse: GL(n) \to GL(n)$

His strategy is that if $Dg$ is of class $C^{r-1}$, then $g$ is of class $C^{r}$

Apparently he considers that $Dg$ as a function from $V$ to $GL(n)$, but functions of class $C^{r}$ are functions from $R^m$ to $R^n$. I know that $GL(n)$ can somehow be viewed as a subspace of $R^{n\times n}$, but I still find it hard to accept his reasoning because he does not strictly follow the definition which restricts $C^r$ functions to be functions on Euclidean spaces.

Comment: $GL(n)$ is a smooth manifold, so the class of $C^r$ functions to or from it is well defined.

Comment: @stewbasic  Are u talking about a more general definition of $C^r$ functions since munkres only deals with functions on Euclidean spaces on this section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm assuming that you're reading "Analysis on Manifolds")

Munkres does not define $C^r$ functions by identifying spaces like $Mat_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ with the appropriate Euclidean space, i.e. he does not define this concept by directly taking the "$r^{th}$ derivative" of the function. This was a misconception I had as well. Rather, he defines a function $f:\Bbb{R}^m\to \Bbb{R}^n$ to be $C^r$ if its partial derivatives of order $r$ can all be defined and are all continuous. This definition is justified by theorem 6.2 of chapter 2, which states that this condition is equivalent to the ordinary definition for $r=1$.

His section on the chain rule discusses the relationship between function composition and continuous differentiability in greater detail.

Comment: Then why does his reasoning hold?

Comment: Oh, I see. He is indeed treating $GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ as a subset of a Euclidean space. This isn't too much of a leap for him, though; $I$ is basically a function that takes in $n^2$ real variables and returns $n^2$ real numbers. Each component of this function is a rational function with a nowhere vanishing denominator, and so it is $C^{infty}$. This proves that $Dg$ is $C^{r-1}$ since it proves that the $r-1$-order partial derivatives each entry of $Dg$ exist.